# Confusion with Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I am working on below REGEX

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]*$/
```

everything is working fine as it shows,

```
abc._-
abc_02.
ab.2_cder
```

**problem -** it is not allowing me to enter [._-] characters like below. I am new and beginner in REGEX.

```
.any character
_any character
-any character
```

Comment: What’s your question? Your regex explicitly forbids your last three examples so of course they are not allowed. Is this not required? What is your regex supposed to achieve?

Comment: That is because the first character must be a letter [a-z].

Comment: `^[a-z]` will match strings that start with a lowercased letter. You could use [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lv9sS2fgvDZC4wyM) to help you with regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 /^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]*$/
```

With `^[a-z]` you're **forcing** the first character of your string to be a lowercase letter.

So it won't work with anything else.

You can change your regex to

```
 /^[a-z0-9_.-]*$/
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your regex means :

- `^` : Starts with...
- `[a-z]` : ...a lowercase letter...
- `[a-z0-9_.-]*` : ...add 0 or more character in `a-z` / `_` / `.` / `-`...
- `$` : ...and reach the end of the line

[image]

If you want to allow one ore more characters in `a-z` / `_` / `.` / `-`, remove the first part :

```
/^[a-z0-9_.-]+$/
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask what you used to generate these beautiful visualizations?

Comment: Of course, via [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com/) or [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/)

Comment: I knew of Debuggex, but not Regexper. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pattern `/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]*$/` description:

```
^             represents the beginning of a line
[a-z]         lowercase letter in the beginning (exactly single time)
[a-z0-9_.-]*  lowercase letters, digits, underscore, dot or hyphen (any one zero or more times) 
$             represents the ending of a line
```

Pictorial representation of your regex pattern:

[image]

Your regex pattern forces it to start it with a small letter in the beginning.

**Note:** space is not added in your regex pattern and it will not match multi-words.